# Quickest way to find the eigenvalues of a binary hermitian matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have an 11x11 matrix and need to find its charactaristic polynomial (or eigenvalues). I would like to do this analytically but was wondering if there's any tricks that can be used due to its hermitian and binary nature.

Comment: When you say "binary", do you mean that you want to work over the field with two elements, or do you just mean that all entries are zeroes and ones?

Comment: @JohnHughes i meant that all entries are zeroes and ones